# Using checkstyle (default) configuration, with lineLength 100 in pre-commit?

Tags: java, checkstyle

### Context

When I run the following pre-commit configuration:

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/gherynos/pre-commit-java
    rev: v0.2.9 # Use the ref you want to point at
    hooks:
      - id: pmd
        # args: ["--cache"]
        # exclude: /test/
      - id: cpd
        # exclude: /test/
      - id: checkstyle
        # Set the path to your Checkstyle configuration file
        # args: ["-c", "checkstyle.xml"]
        # exclude: /test/
```

checkstyle throws 32 warnings of various types, including `InvalidJavadocPosition`. That is as expected. However, by default it uses a lineLength of 80 characters, whereas google_style_java uses 100 characters. I would like to change checkstyle to use 100 characters, which I did by adding a `checkstyle.xml` file with content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <!-- Configure the line length check with a maximum limit of 80 characters -->
    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="max" value="80"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

and enabling: `args: ["-c", "checkstyle.xml"]`.

### Issue

However, the latter configuration makes checkstyle **only** check for lineLength. To resolve this, I could create a custom checkstyle configuration with all the checks that checkstyle supports. However, that is quite labour intensive, and more importantly, it requires me to manually update the configuration if checkstyle updates. Hence, I would like to "just use the default checkstyle setting, as pre-commit uses it", with the exception that the line-length should be 100 instead of 80.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask, how can I use the default checkstyle configuration that pre-commit uses, with the exception of the linelenght check of 100 (instead of 80)

Comment: this isn't specific to pre-commit so I've removed the tags for it

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found by including the other checks inside the `TreeWalker` like:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">

        <!-- Formatting Check: Enforces a maximum line length of 80 characters -->
        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="max" value="100"/>
        </module>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Limits the length of a file to 1000 lines -->
        <module name="FileLength">
            <property name="max" value="1000"/>
        </module>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Enforces Javadoc comments for package-info.java files -->
        <module name="JavadocPackage"/>

    <!-- TreeWalker Module: Performs checks on the abstract syntax tree -->
    <module name="TreeWalker">




        <!-- Formatting Check: Ensures consistent indentation -->
        <!-- <module name="Indentation"> -->
            <!-- <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="caseIndent" value="0"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="throwsIndent" value="2"/> -->
        <!-- </module> -->

        <!-- Formatting Check: Enforces right curly brace placement -->
        <!-- <module name="RightCurly"> -->
            <!-- <property name="option" value="alone"/> -->
        <!-- </module> -->

        <!-- Formatting Check: Enforces whitespace around certain tokens -->
        <module name="WhitespaceAround">
            <property name="allowEmptyConstructors" value="true"/>
            <property name="allowEmptyMethods" value="true"/>
        </module>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Disallows empty blocks -->
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
            <property name="option" value="text"/>
        </module>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Enforces the use of braces for control statements -->
        <module name="NeedBraces"/>

        <!-- Formatting Check: Enforces consistent whitespace usage -->
        <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>


        <!-- Code Structure Check: Checks for redundant import statements -->
        <module name="RedundantImport"/>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Disallows star import statements -->
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Checks the placement of left curly braces -->
        <module name="LeftCurly"></module>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for local final variables -->
        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for local variables -->
        <module name="LocalVariableName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for member variables -->
        <module name="MemberName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for method names -->
        <module name="MethodName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for package names -->
        <module name="PackageName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for method parameters -->
        <module name="ParameterName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for static variables -->
        <module name="StaticVariableName"/>

        <!-- Naming Convention Check: Enforces naming conventions for type names (classes, interfaces, enums, etc.) -->
        <module name="TypeName"/>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Disallows unused import statements -->
        <module name="UnusedImports"/>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Disallows unused private fields -->
        <!-- <module name="UnusedPrivateField"/> -->

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Enforces Javadoc comments for methods and classes -->
        <module name="JavadocMethod"/>
        <module name="JavadocType"/>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Disallows trailing whitespace -->
        <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter"/>

        <!-- Code Structure Check: Disallows whitespace before a semicolon -->
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>

        <!-- Add: // CHECKSTYLE:OFF to the top of the file for which you want to skip checkstyle checks. -->
        <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
    </module>

</module>
```